# How to use the spread operator to get all parameters of a function that has named parameters?

Tags: javascript

[Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) can be used to get parameters of a variadic function, e.g.

```
(...args) => {
    console.log(args);
};

args('a', 'b', 'c');

// a
// b
// c
```

However, is there a way to get all parameters where some of the parameters are already named?, e.g.

```
(foo, bar, baz, ...args) => {
    console.log(args);
};
```

There is no other way that I can think of other than contacting a list using named parameters and variadic parameters, e.g.

```
(foo, bar, baz, ...args) => {
    console.log([
        foo,
        bar,
        baz,
        ...args
    ]);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this the other way with [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
let f = (...args) => {
     let [foo, bar, baz] = args;
     console.log(foo, bar, baz, args);
}

f(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
// result: 1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```